# What should we do when same column fields occurring multiple time in many tables?

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2012, database-normalization

My question is that I have more than 20 tables in my database. Now problem is that there are some columns which are occurring in most of all tables so in that case what should I do? Do I put that all columns in every table or there is any better way to solve this problem?

**Country** table example:

```
CountryID, CountryName, 
AddedBy, AddedTime,
LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdateDTime,
DeletedBy, DeletedTime, DeleteFlag
```

As we can see above table structure there are 9 columns and except of `CountryId` and `CountrynName` column, all are occurring in most of tables.

I don't want keep above repeating column in all tables. So if there is any solution than please let me know.

Thanks & regards

Comment: Those "system" columns typically show up in all the actual data tables that your system has - but unfortunately, there's really no provision in any relational database system to put these in a "base" table or something and then "inherit" from that (as we could do in C# or Java). If your table needs that information - you need to add those columns to the table - each one of them.

Comment: @marc_s for your description

Comment: Columns like "added by" are really process metadata.  You shouldn't  use the same design principles for this kind of data that you would for subject matter data.

Comment: search for History Table pattern

Answer (score 1):

Its a design question and there is no one answer for it.

You should consider a table as a container that contains fields which describe the object. I would keep all the fields describing my object together in my table and can have a common or a base class to contain the common columns of different tables.

It make sense to combine two tables if they are similar. eg: Category and Sub-Catgory.

```
Category Table

- CatID
- Name
- Description
- Flag


SubCategory Table

- SubCatID
- ParentCatID
- Name
- Description
- Flag
```

Now I can have these two tables separate as shown above or I can combine them.

> Category - Sub-Category : OneToMany relation

**Note:** Combining these two tables make sense here, as they are same objects, describing same things.

I will combine them as follow:

```
Category Table

- Cat_id
- Parent_Cat_ID
- Name
- Description
- Flag
```

**Note:** `Parent_cat_id` could be `null`. It will be `null` for `Categories` and would contain a `parentCatID` for `subcategories`.

If you have tables containing same information. Then you should combine them, otherwise keep them separate.

Comment: Thanks for reply but in my case i will have to keep them separate

Answer (score 0):

You could consider having an `audit` table with columns: `AddedBy`, `AddedTime`, `LastUpdatedBy`, `LastUpdateDTime`, `DeletedBy`, `DeletedTime`, `DeleteFlag`. Then your country table would look like:

```
Country
    - CountryID,
    - CountryName,
    - AuditID // foreign key to audit table
```

But you should think hard whether it makes sense to have a separate audit table like this. It would really depend on how frequently you need the audit data when you query for the main entity.

By the way, if your need to "avoid duplication" is coming from an object oriented way of thinking (inheritance?), remember that they're not really applicable in the relational world. You could use an ORM to model your persistent entities and configure how it should create the underlying tables. E.g. in hibernate (the ORM that I use in my projects), I would define an `Audit` entity and use it as a component or a joined association depending on whether I always need audit data or not.

Comment: That was a very simplistic definition of audit table. If you really want to create a separate table you could consider adding another column indicating for which table/entity an audit record exists